# MongoDB Mongoose - Discriminator Performance

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoose-schema

I'm currently presented with the problem of storing a somewhat large variety of different subtypes that all share similar properties but have a few differing.

Normally, if I didnt expect a lot of reads and updates, I wouldn't hesitate to create a basetype and use a discriminator for each subtype to keep them grouped in the same collection as well as allow me to perform aggregate queries on all of the subtypes. Unfortunately, I expect a large number of  basic read/update operations, and a slightly less large number of create operations. In such a case performance becomes a non-negligible concern.

I would like to know if anyone has any idea of the performance impact of storing a variety of models in separate collections, vs storing them all in one collection with discriminator keys.

Thanks.